# Why don't string pointers point to the first address?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I'm trying to understand how string pointers work(std::string*). 
I created an array of character pointers to a string. The string pointer for some reason points to an address that is 4 addresses before the first character's address, but it still prints the correct string when I deference it(I guess it's programmed to print whatever is 4 addresses from it till the null0), but why? Why 4 addresses behind, why not just start from the first character?

```
int main() {
    std::string x = "hello";
    char* ptrs[6];
    for (int i = 0; i <= x.length(); i++) {
        ptrs[i] = &x[i];
        std::cout << (void*)ptrs[i] << "  " << *ptrs[i] << "\n";
    }
    std::string* y = &x;
    std::cout << "\n" << y << "\n";
    std::cout << *y << "\n";
    std::cout << (char*)y;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0115F9A4  h
0115F9A5  e
0115F9A6  l
0115F9A7  l
0115F9A8  o
0115F9A9

0115F9A0
hello
╚ë2hello
```

Comment: `std::string*` points to the internals of the `string` object, not the character string itself.  Where that is stored is a private matter.

Comment: `std::string` is an object with multiple member inside of it.  It's not the same thing as a c-string.

Comment: @PaulSanders Private-ish. Use the member function `.data()` to get the pointer to the beginning of the character array.

Comment: @sweenish Sure, but you can't make any assumptions about where, within the guts of the `string` object, that pointer (or the data it points to) is stored.

Comment: Yeah. Just wanted to clarify that it is possible to get the location.

Comment: Note that if your compiler's `std::string` class implements Short String Optimzation than the location of the string's character buffer depends on the *length* of the string's characters. It may be a buffer stored entirely inside the `std::string` object itself, or it may be a buffer allocated elsewhere in memory. So the pointer returned by `string::data()` can change over time as the contents of the `std::string` change.

Comment: If you want the character data: [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str). Note, in C++ don't just slap on arbitrary casts like `(char*)y`. That's not valid. Use [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) and **pay very close attention to compiler warnings and errors**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this very simplistic representation of the `std::string` container

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct StringContainer{
    explicit StringContainer(const char* str) {
        len_ = strlen(str);
        data_ = (char*)malloc(len_);
        for(int i = 0; i <len_; ++i){
            data_[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
    const char& operator[](size_t idx) {
        static char nullChar = '\0';
        return (idx < len_) ? data_[idx]: nullChar;
    }

    ~StringContainer() {
        if(data_){
            free(data_);
        }
    }

    size_t length() const {
        return len_;
    }
    private:
    char* data_;
    size_t len_;
};

int main() {
    StringContainer str("test");
    std::cout<<"Address of str: "<<std::hex<<(void*)&str<<'\n';
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        std::cout<<"Address of "<<str[i]<<": "<<std::hex<<(void*)&str[i]<<'\n';
    }
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/q9TKf5Mds):

```
Address of str: 0x7ffd85ed1108
Address of t: 0x1865eb0
Address of e: 0x1865eb1
Address of s: 0x1865eb2
Address of t: 0x1865eb3
```

The *container* (`std::string` or `StringContainer` in the example) is a separate entity from its data. Hence the different addresses. In this example `(void*)&str` gives the address of the container object which encapsulates the actual string data. `&str[i]` gives the address of that *actual* string data. Using `std::string` that looks as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str("test");
    std::cout<<"Address of str is "<<std::hex<<(void*)&str<<'\n';
    for(char& a: str){
        std::cout<<"Address of "<<a<<" is "<<std::hex<<(void*)&a<<'\n';
    }
    std::cout<<"Address of the data of str is "<<(void*)str.c_str()<<'\n';
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/bn6WxzK4c):

```
Address of str is 0x7fff0634b208
Address of t is 0x7fff0634b218
Address of e is 0x7fff0634b219
Address of s is 0x7fff0634b21a
Address of t is 0x7fff0634b21b
Address of the data of str is 0x7fff0634b218
```

As can be observed, the address of the **data** of `str` is `0x7fff0634b218` which matches with that of `t` i.e `0x7fff0634b218` but the address of the object `str` in itself is different `0x7fff0634b208`.

Comment: So tldr, the 'container' is separate from the 'data' right?

Comment: @HaydenSoares That's right. The reason why the address in your particular example is within a few bytes of its actual data is well-explained by the other answer but in _general_ there can be no assumptions made on how the container actually stores its data and it's accessor methods like `[]`, `at()`, `front()` etc. should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Implementations of the class `std::string` usually use the small-object optimization. It means that  it is not necessary that an object of the type `std::string` allocates dynamically memory for a stored string. That is within an object of the type `std::string` there are reserved some small extent of memory where a string can be stored if it is not greater than the size of the extent of memory.

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
    {
        s += 'A';
        std::cout << i << ": " << &s << " -> " << ( void * )&s[0] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
sizeof( s ) = 32
0: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
1: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
2: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
3: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
4: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
5: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
6: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
7: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
8: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
9: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
10: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
11: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
12: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
13: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
14: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x7ffe94e82110
15: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x55ff0bc85e80
16: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x55ff0bc85e80
17: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x55ff0bc85e80
18: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x55ff0bc85e80
19: 0x7ffe94e82100 -> 0x55ff0bc85e80
```

From the output of the program it is seen that the size of an object of the type `std::string` is equal to `32`. It does not depend on the size of a stored string.

Also from the output it is seen that the address of the stored string is always equal to `0x7ffe94e82110` until the size of the string is greater than 15. And this address is greater of the address of the starting position of the object by 0x10. That is this address is inside the extent of memory allocated for the object of the type `std::string`.

So strings with lengths less than 16 are stored within the object itself. For strings the length of which is greater than 15 the object allocates dynamically a memory.  The size of an object of the type `std::string` itself is not being changed in this case. It just has a pointer as its data member that points to the allocated memory.

As for this code snippet in your question

```
std::string* y = &x;
std::cout << "\n" << y << "\n";
std::cout << *y << "\n";
```

then in this statement

```
std::cout << "\n" << y << "\n";
```

there is being outputted the address of the object of the type `std::string` itself.

In this statement

```
std::cout << *y << "\n";
```

there is being outputted the stored string in the object because the expression `*y` gives an object of the type `std::string` and for such an object of the type `std::string` there is defined the `operator <<` that outputs stored in the object string.

As for this statement

```
std::cout << (char*)y;
```

then in general it does not make a sense because it tries to output data members of an object of the type `std::string` as a character array that contains a string. It results in undefined behavior.